# Cordova hybrid app failing in qhd resolution devices

Tags: android, cordova

The hybrid app I have developed works fine in all the android devices expect when I check it on device with dimensions more than 2560 x 1440 px (qhd). The app work fine if I remove the splashscreen. Any support is appreciated.

Cordova version: 8
Android-cordova: 7.1.4
Splashscreen plugin : 5.0.2

Comment: Sounds like a bug with the splash screen plugin, did you report or ask for help in their GitHub issues section?

Comment: Thanks @andreszs. I was able to find a similar issue reported in their github issues. Will try out the solution they have mentioned.- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/issues/165